# Create Criteria range, modify columns and Advanced Filtering in Excel

Tags: excel, filter, filtering, named-ranges

I'm struggling with creating a proper criteria range for my database in Excel. The problem is quite complex to me. This is what the problem looks like:

> Assign range name called database to *range A14:J26*. Assign range name called Criteria to the *range A7:J9*. (**This part is done**).
>   Create column labels for the Criteria range and replace the **Edition Size** with a second **Release Date** column label. ***Set the following conditions in the Criteria range***:
>  
>   - Sold-out limited-edition canvases released after 1/1/2000 and before 12/31/2003
>   - Sold-out limited-edition prints released after 1/1/2000 and before 12/31/2003
>   Create an advanced filter using the database list and Criteria range. Filter everything in place.

So this would be the problem. The ***bold italic*** part is the biggest part confusing me. I don't really know how to achieve this.

See the sheet below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xjZ62WK7gqbo58JBCfwYaMV7xLZkhBMPiUQsGdt7WUo/edit?usp=sharing

---

**EDIT**

I have copied all column names from *Database records* and pasted them in the criteria range. Then I added the following formula in **K7**:

```
=AND(OR(F15>E$8, F15<F$8), OR(D15="Limited Edition Print", D15="Limited Edition Canvas"))
```

But unfortunately this is not filtering my results as I want them. Any ideas?

Comment: [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Comment: @Jeeped Fixed. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria area requires values on the same row for an AND condition and and values on different rows for an OR condition.

[image: Advanced Filer AND date criteria OR date criteria]

To get a date range, you are going to have to put two dates on the same row so one of the unused columns will be used to make a second release date criteria filter.

To get the same results while the *Type* is either Limited Edition Print OR Limited Edition Canvas, put these entries on separate rows.